# iPhone 4 does not wake up from being locked

Tags: iphone, sleep-wake

My iPhone 4 periodically does not wake up from being locked. I have to wake it by holding the home and power buttons. This is happening a lot more frequently as of late than before. It has the latest OS. It seems quite [a few people](https://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=2476608&start=0&tstart=0) have the same problem. Does anyone know a solution to this problem? None that I found on the Apple forum seems to solve it.

Comment: smae thing is happening to my iphone 3gs. with 4.2.1. I even tried restoring. Didnt help.

Comment: Is it not waking up regardless of which button you press? I ask only because the home button on my iP4 went mushy and became almost useless.

Comment: @philip I'm pretty sure the buttons work perfectly.

Comment: I don't know of a solution but I know of how I got in a similar situation, I was in a foreign city, data roaming and compass/location services (Map and Gowalla) were always running. One night it ended up like how you described when I tried to wake from using the Camera app. I am not sure how many apps/services running you can have open at once because I have curbed my use and watched for unused open apps since then and I have not had any problems.

Comment: Like Philip, my home button does not work from a particular angle. Though the sleep button has always worked. I occasionally have this problem with an intensive process running, it just takes a while to wake. But if yours never wakes, different problem. Just saying, consider a minor hardware problem first.

Answer (score 2):

You could try going by the Apple Store to meet with a Genius (if there is one close enough to you). They have diagnostics they'll run for free to see if something weird is going on with your phone. [Make an appointment online.](http://www.apple.com/retail/geniusbar/)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried restoring the iPhone via iTunes? You should sync the iPhone first to back up everything, then press the Restore button in the device management screen.

Comment: yes and it didn't help. as noted by other people too: http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=958949

Comment: Taking in to your local Apple Store might be your next best option.

Comment: @Jin Have you tried restoring the OS, but not restoring your data?

Comment: @kyle I tried that. looks like i may have to take it to the Apple store..

Answer (score 0):

You could try to reset it: **`Settings > General > Reset > Reset All Settings`**. There might be some corrupted preferences somewhere.

Try to sync your iPhone and look into your `~/Library/iTunes/.../Logs` (sorry, can't remember the exact path and I don't have a Mac right now).
And try to find out if there's a crash file that match the time of the issue. From there you'll be able to define if it's an app running in the background or iOS-related.

If none of the above, it might be hardware-related (maybe you're holding it wrong!) and will have to send it to an Apple Store.